# Redirecting to device settings

Tags: c#, android, redirect, windows-mobile, mobile-safari

Say I have a mobile optimized website which runs with a lot of javascript on it to create awesome effects, and a user enters the website via a mobile browser which doesn't have javascript activated.

Is it then possible to (through a button click) redirect that user to his/hers browser settings?

> You need to have JavaScript activated in order to browse this site properly.
>   [Click here to change  your settings](http://redirect-to-settings.mobile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, you can create an `intent:` URL that references an `ACTION_SETTINGS` `Intent`, though I have not tried this. Off the top of my head, the simplest way to construct that URL is to generate a scrap Android project and call:

```
Log.d("Something", new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS).toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME));
```

then check LogCat for the URL that you would put in the Web site. Of course, this URL will only work on Android devices.

Comment: I imagine this being rather App featured than Web featured? Is this approach plausible through websites using e.g. C#?

Comment: @Dandroid: "I imagine this being rather App featured than Web featured?" -- I have no idea what this means. URLs are rather commonplace in Web apps. URLs with the `intent:` scheme are only relevant for Web apps being used on an Android device. "Is this approach plausible through websites using e.g. C#?" -- a URL is a sequence of characters. While I have never developed in C#, one would hope that it supports the concept of a sequence of characters. The Android project I suggest creating simply tells you the sequence of characters to paste into the appropriate spot for the link in your Web app.

Answer (score 0):

I only know Windows Mobile (and there, only up to v6.1), but I would guess your clients would have to have some app of yours prior installed to access features of the device itself.

If websites could access a device's features, it would be viewed as a virus.