# Redirect to android setting

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a redirection to the settings wallpaper when the user press a button, but I read the documentation and not found something similar. Can some help me?

I try with

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS.getClass() );
startActivity( i );
```

Reference: [Redirecting to device settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473931/redirecting-to-device-settings)

but, no working

Comment: What happens when you try? Is there an error in the logcat output?

Comment: this is the log @EdwardFalk  FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ss.wpaper/com.ss.wpaper.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.ss.wpaper/java.lang.String}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.ss.wpaper/java.lang.String}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? –

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(this, android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS.getClass() ) It will open activity belong to your app. So there is ActivityNotFoundException raised

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent wallpaperChooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER);
startActivity(wallpaperChooser);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
    startActivity( i );
```